# WIX Installer: ensure successive Version numbers on build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to automate my Wix installer builds with my Visual Studio Builds. I am grabbing the application's Application Version via this in my installer.wicproj:

```xml
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <!-- Get Assembly Version -->
        <!-- Update built assembly below-->
        <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="..\DavesDonutsInstallerTest\bin\Debug\DavesDonuts.exe">
            <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion"/>
        </GetAssemblyIdentity>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <DefineConstants>BuildVersion=%(AssemblyVersion.Version)</DefineConstants>
        </PropertyGroup>        
        
    </Target>
```

Then I am using this in my main Product.wxs to populate the version number:

```xml
    <Product Id="*" 
                Name="!(loc.ProductName)"
                Language="1033" 
                Version="$(var.BuildVersion)"
                Manufacturer="!(loc.Developer)" 
                UpgradeCode="{40CB43C5-1910-4B9D-ABD2-92F620E7125C}">
```

This works well. However, what it does mean is that if I build the installer without increasing the Application Version in the main Project properties, the installer builds fine. However, if I run this on a dev machine, the installer runs again and I get two entries for the app in the uninstall facilities (essentially having two or more installations of the same app.

I don't want to be manually updating `Product ID` every time, thus the auto-gen.

I would like to have a system where the Wix installer builder detects that it's making a build with the same version number as last time, it stops the build and places a warning in the output window.

I would image this would be done in the install.wixproj `BeforeBuild` function, but have no idea how to implement it. I'd imagine it working thus. On a successful build, the build version is written to a text file in the WixINstaller project folder (via `AfterBuild`??). Then on next `BeforeBuild` this is retrieved and compared to the 'present' Application Version and if they match, the build is stopped and an error is thrown.

Brownie points: some routine to figure if it's a lower build version to control for mistake in setting the Application Version.

Wix seems powerful, but a little baffling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage this totally outside of WIX via the Pre-Build Build Event in VS. Just place this batch scripting in your Pre-Build box. Also managed the brownie point of additionally checking for lower version numbers than the last. It also posts Errors and Warnings in VS's Errors panel.

[image]

Or

[image]

```
::Error Thrown by Build Script
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:: SETTINGS VARS
:: exceptionOnMatchingVersion can be Warning, Error or None. Be careful of trailing spaces
set exceptionOnMatchingVersion=Error

echo ==========================
echo PRE-BUILD EVENTS
echo ==========================
echo Build Type: $(ConfigurationName)
echo Project: $(ProjectName)

echo.
echo Checking Build Assembly Version for Wix Installer Build

:: PROCESS VARS
set /p lastversion=<lastbuildversion.txt

set version=0.0.0.0
FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2 %%i in ('findstr /b /c:"[assembly: AssemblyVersion(" $(ProjectDir)\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs') do (
  set version=%%i
)

set concatVersion=0.0.0
    set /a presentMajor=0
    set /a presentMinor=0
    set /a presentPatch=0
    set /a lastMajor=0
    set /a lastMinor=0
    set /a lastPatch=0
    
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%a in ("%version%") do (
    set concatVersion=%%a.%%b.%%c
    set /a presentMajor=%%a
    set /a presentMinor=%%b
    set /a presentPatch=%%c
    )
    
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%a in ("%lastversion%") do (
    set /a lastMajor=%%a
    set /a lastMinor=%%b
    set /a lastPatch=%%c
    )

echo Build Full Assembly Version: %version%
echo Concatinated Assembly Version: %concatVersion%
echo Last Concatinated Assembly Version: %lastversion%

set lowerVersion=False

If "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Release" (
    If "%lastversion%" == "%concatVersion%" (
        If NOT %exceptionOnMatchingVersion% == None (
            echo.
            echo ======================================================================================================================================================
            echo = ALERT: The last Assembly Version is the same as this Build's Assembly Version. This causes issues with the installer. Please ammend the version number.
            echo = *** YOU ARE ADVISED NOT TO DEPLOY THIS VERSION ***
            echo ======================================================================================================================================================
            echo.
            If %exceptionOnMatchingVersion% == Warning (
                echo Warning: The last Assembly Version is the same as this Build's Assembly Version. This causes issues with the installer. Please ammend the version number.
                )
            If %exceptionOnMatchingVersion% == Error (
                echo Error: The last Assembly Version is the same as this Build's Assembly Version. This causes issues with the installer. Please ammend the version number. BUILD STOPPED.
                exit 1
                )
        )
        
    ) else (
    
        if %presentPatch% LSS %lastPatch% (
            if %presentMinor% LEQ %lastMinor% (
             set "lowerVersion=True"
            )
        ) else (
        
            if %presentMinor% LSS %lastMinor% (
                if %presentMajor% LEQ %lastMajor% (
                 set "lowerVersion=True"
                )
            ) else (
            
                if %presentMajor% LSS %lastMajor% (
                set "lowerVersion=True"
                )
            )           
        )
        
        if "!lowerVersion!"=="True" (
            echo.
            echo ======================================================================================================================================================
            echo = FATAL EXCEPTION: You are trying to build the assembly to a lower version numer. Please check your numbering. BUILD STOPPED..
            echo = *** YOU ARE ADVISED NOT TO DEPLOY THIS VERSION ***
            echo ======================================================================================================================================================
            echo.
            echo Error: You are trying to build the assembly to a lower version numer. Please check your numbering. BUILD STOPPED. This version: %concatVersion%. Last Version: %lastversion%
            exit 1
        ) else (
            echo ======================================================================================================================================================
            echo = VERSION NUMBER VALID: Proceeding to build. \o/
            echo ======================================================================================================================================================
            )
        
    )   
)

:: echo Lower Version: %lowerVersion%

echo %concatVersion%> lastbuildversion.txt
```

Comment: Hi stigzler, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as  an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)